# Resque distributed workers with a different code base?

Tags: resque

I am looking at using resque.  I have two separate code bases -- I want my web app to enqueue a job that a worker on another server with my other codebase will run. Given that the web app will enqueue a class, it seems as though the code needs to be duplicated.

Could I have an empty class in my web app that gets enqueued and then a real class in the worker codebase?  That doesn't seem very DRY.  Is there a solution to this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have to repeat your class name but none of the internal methods or code. It serves as a reminder from your main application that such a job even exists.

```
# executed by external job workers
module SomeJob
  extend Resque::Plugins::Meta

  @queue = :processor_X

  def perform; end
end
```

Comment: rmw What was the use-case? @databyte How to pass the params?

Comment: @rmw Can you gist your example? I think this will address my issue as well to separate the code base.